# Does React Typescript works in Internet Explorer 11?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have many React applications that works in Internet Explorer 11 (With polyfills). I would like to use TypeScript in my next applications, so I developed my first one using the same technologies and concepts from the other apps. The problem is that I can just see a blank page in that browser, and many errors (Translated from Spanish):

> Invalid range in character set.
>
> Object does not accept 'repeat' property or method (This one appears 26 times).

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "reportes",
  "homepage": "http://localhost:8080/isset/view/funeraria/reportes",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.8",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.47",
    "@mdi/js": "^5.0.45",
    "@mdi/react": "^1.4.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.3",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "exceljs": "^3.8.2",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "react-select": "^3.1.0",
    "react-to-print": "^2.6.3",
    "typescript": "~3.7.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all",
      "ie 11"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version",
      "ie 11"
    ]
  }
}
```

And I have this imports at my index.tsx:

```
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie9';
import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';
```

Can you help me to fix this?

Comment: it's an exceljs issue read this page: https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs/issues/1177

Answer (score 0):

`repeat` is [not supported by IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat#Browser_compatibility). You need to [add polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat#Polyfill) for it.

For the other errors, you could also check if you used some syntax not supported by IE and try to find the polyfills for them or use some transpiler such as Babel. You could also refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36723931/javascript-error-in-typescript-generated-js-in-ie11/36723994#36723994).

Besides, please add `import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11'; import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';` at the first line of your src/index.tsx.